# Intersection between an AP and GP (solving equation)

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Given the following equation:

$$1000+(N-1)200=500\cdot 1.2^N-1$$

I need to find the value for $N$.

When there was no $N$ in the left-hand-side I will be able to solve the equation with logarithms. Unfortunately, now I do not know how I need to solve this equation.

I want to solve the equation algebraically instead of graphical.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason to think there is an algebraic solution to this equation? My guess would be that you can only do a numerical method.

Comment: Can you explain/show that to me? How will such a method (and solution) look like?

Comment: One thing you can do is move everything to the LHS and say that expression should be zero. Then, find two values of N such that this expression has opposite signs. Then, move to the mid point and see what the sign of the expression is. Keep the original value of N that is opposite to the sign of the mid point and now these become your two points. Now you have a tighter sandwich. Repeat this until your sandwich is so tight, its practically one point.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm

Comment: unless for a specific case there won't be one answer likely.

Comment: Is the right-hand side in the current edit of your question correct? The left-hand side is indeed an arithmetic progression, but the right-hand side is not a geometric progression. Did you mean $500\cdot 1.2^{N-1}$ for the right? That would make it a standard expression for a geometric progression.

Comment: @RoryDaulton, You are correct, of course.

Comment: I guess the value should be near $n=-2.387001$